# "Specified URL Already Exists" Error on Product Import in magento 2.1.4

Tags: magento-2.1.4

I am getting an error as "Specified URL key already exists in row(s): 1"
when I am trying to import the products using a csv file.
The product I am trying to import is the one that already is created and i am trying to update only the product attributes with the sku field. No url_key field in csv.
Anyone can help me in solving this????????

Answer (score 1):

Follow this link it has so many solutions for this issue.

```
https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/6671
```